# OpenCart Category and Product View blank in Frontend

Tags: opencart

I "inherited" an existing and working install of OpenCart 1.5.2.1.

For test purpuses I wanted to set up a dev site on my local server. So I installed it locally and copied the DB over.

I can log into the backend without any issues - stores are set up, all the products and categories are there as well.

On the frontend, I can visit the home page of the store, and the list of categories gets displayed correctly, including the product count per category.

However, when I try to view the category listings, or an individual product for that matter, I get a blank page.

I am not getting a PHP error - I appended

```
display_errors = 1;
error_reporting = E_ALL;
log_errors = 1;
```

to the php.ini in the cart root folder.

From within the OpenCart Error Log, I am getting the following error message:

```
2013-03-13 18:51:15 - PHP Notice:  Error: Column 'product_id' cannot be null<br />Error No: 1048<br />SELECT DISTINCT *, p [...] AND p2s.store_id = '5' in /path/to/root/system/database/mysql.php on line 49
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

** UPDATE: **

The full query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name, pd.creator, pd.keyword, pd.circa, pd.year, pd.century, pd.decade, pd.scenelocation, pd.fm_quicksearch AS fm_quicksearch, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '8' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '8' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '8') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '1') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '1') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '1') AS length_class, (select (r.sum + p.rat)/(r.tot + p.tot) from (select COALESCE(j.sum,0) as sum , COALESCE(j.tot,0) as tot from (select SUM(rating) as sum , COUNT(rating) as tot, product_id from rating where product_id = '9206' group by product_id) j right join product on product.product_id = j.product_id where product.product_id = '9206') r, (select product_id, COALESCE(rating,0) as rat, count(rating) as tot from product where product_id = '9206' and rating > 0) p ) AS rating, p.sort_order FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '9206' AND pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '5'
```

**UPDATE**

I suspect it has something to do with the MySQL or PHP configuration. Because when I run the same query on the live site, it works without fail.

**UPDATE**

The issue is related to my local MySQL install. When using the online DB all is fine. Someone in the OpenCart Forum - [Link to Post](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=97562&p=390203#p390203) indicated the following:

> This error originates from an insert query on a specific contribution which the author has >untestedly tried to add a null statement which an auto-incremented field will reject >especially starting on mySQL 5.1+ . This methodology from mySQL developers has been blocked >ages ago.
>
> Contact the author to address this issue by stating that the auto-incremented field does NOT >require to be addressed in the query as it is already creating an incremented value >automatically along with the executed query.

It might be along these lines. The query itself is not an insert, but it has most likely to do with that. I'll look further into the matter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the answer indeed had to do with my local MySQL install. I moved it to a different server, and it worked just fine. Thank you for the input! Sorry to not have a more specific answer than that. I just wanted to tie up a loose end with this post.

Answer (score 0):

Set “Output Compression Level” to 0 in the System > Settings > Server tab.
Then in php.ini file display_errors = 1; error_reporting = E_ALL; log_errors = 1;

So the problem is with the 'product_id' . In the page controller page check the product id (just echo it). then check the model query. the problem is product id only.

Comment: The error reporting has been set to those values already. Basically the SQL query which is causing the error, is in the getProduct($product_id) function in the catalog/model/catalog/product.php. We do pass a product _id, correctly, but it throws the error. I have updated the original question to include the full SQL query.

What puzzles me is that the live site of the store is working perfectly well, but the dev site is having this error.